# Change Json output, return `icd3_code_id` as `:id`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

At the time my controller looks like this:

```
def search
    @icd4 = Icd4Code.search_full(params[:search]).first(20)
    render json: { icd: @icd4.as_json(:only => [:bezeichnung, :nummer, :id])}
end
```

What i would like to change is that my code does not return `@icd4.id` as `:id` but instead `@icd4.icd3_code_id` as `:id`

So `render json: { icd: @icd4 }` would look like this:

```
{"icd":[{"id":6,"nummer":"A00.1","bezeichnung":"Cholera","icd3_code_id":3,"created_at":"2014-02-28T19:38:20.530Z","updated_at":"2014-02-28T19:38:20.530Z"},{"id":7,"nummer":"A00.1","bezeichnung":"El-Tor-Cholera","icd3_code_id":3,"created_at":"2014-02-28T19:38:20.533Z","updated_at":"2014-02-28T19:38:20.533Z"}]}
```

**My actual code `render json: { icd: @icd4.as_json(:only => [:bezeichnung, :nummer, :id])}` returns this:**

```
{"icd":[{"id":6,"nummer":"A00.1","bezeichnung":"Cholera"},{"id":7,"nummer":"A00.1","bezeichnung":"El-Tor-Cholera"}]}
```

**And i would like this output:**

```
{"icd":[{"id":3,"nummer":"A00.1","bezeichnung":"Cholera"},{"id":7,"nummer":"A00.1","bezeichnung":"El-Tor-Cholera"}]}
```

How can i achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to cleverly change the value something like this

```
def search
   @icd4 = Icd4Code.search_full(params[:search]).first(20)
   r = icd: @icd4.as_json(:only => [:bezeichnung, :nummer, :icd3_code_id])
   final_value = []
   r["icd"].each do |h|
    f = {} 
    h.map do |k,v|
    if k == 'icd3_code_id'
     f["id"] = v
    else
      f[k] = v
    end
   end
  final_value << f
 end
 render json: final_value
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely take a look at [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) and [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) gems.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers

http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper

although I use Draper in a bit different way then Ryan Bates does, usually I do something like this:

```
render json: item.decorate.as_json
```

for example as a simplest solution you could have this class:

```
class Icd4CodeDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  decorates :icd4_code
  delegate_all

  def as_json(options={})
    {
      id: icd3_code_id,
      bezeichnung: bezeichnung,
      nummer: nummer
    }
  end
end
```

and then in your controller you could just do:

```
render json: @icd4.decorate.as_json
```

Although I think it would be better to keep things correct in `as_json` method and have `id` value returned for `id` property and create a decorator class inherited from Draper::CollectionDecorator and define there your custom method, something like:

```
class Icd4CodesDecorator < Draper::CollectionDecorator
  def as_search_json
    object.map do |o|
      {
        id: icd3_code_id,
        bezeichnung: bezeichnung,
        nummer: nummer
      }
    end
  end
end
```

and then in your controller you could do:

```
render json: Icd4CodesDecorator.new(@icd4).as_search_json
```

This way you can easily create and maintain any number of versions of json output for your models.

Answer (score 1):

Without a serializer you can iterate through the items and their keys and rename the key when you find yours.

```
@icd4 = Icd4Code.search_full(params[:search]).first(20)
data = @icd4.as_json(:only => [:bezeichnung, :nummer, :icd3_code_id]).tap do |icd4_json|
    icd4_json.each do |icd4_item|
        icd4_item.each do |key|
            icd4_item[ 'id' ] = icd4_item.delete( key ) if key == 'icd3_code_id'
        end
    end
end
render json: { icd4: data }
```